# Wrong characters when printing text of JTextPane in Java Swing

Tags: java, html, swing, character-encoding

Here's my code:

```
private JTextPane htmlTextPane = new JTextPane();
htmlTextPane.setContentType("text/html;Charset=CP1251");
```

When I try to get out text from JTextPane to console like this:

```
System.out.println(htmlTextPane.getText());
```

some symbols, for example &, look in console like &amp

What do I need to do to get symbols not like HTML code?

Comment: Depends on the console you are using. Java does not dictate to the console what characters it should be able to print